# struts 1.2 values in ActionForm passed to Action execute method are nulls

Tags: java, weblogic, struts

I'm doing the maintenance of an old Struts 1.2 application. (It's too big to post.)

The Struts application is deployed on WebLogic server 12.1.1 using jdk1.6.0_45. When I click on the Submit button in any form of the application, there is a NullPointerException. When I checked, I found that the values in ActionForm passed to Action execute method are nulls. There is a manual for installation of the application in development mode. There is more than one installation created by following the installation manual. One of the installations thus installed earlier is working fine. So, I guess that the problem is with some configuration. Due to what reasons can the values in ActionForm passed to Action execute method be nulls? struts-config.xml is identical in working and non working installations. I searched for a solution a lot, but could not find any that would work. Please help.

Comment: I can't think of anything off the top of my head, and with nothing to go on, it'll be really, really difficult to help. [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I corrected this problem by applying a weblogic server patch